# How to use angularjs promise for some object

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am learning angularjs promise and want to implement in my code. I am trying to use a promise in a function which invoke before the object initialization. Here is a code

```
$scope.turnOffLocalAudio = function () {
    if ($scope.currentCall) {
        if ($scope.currentCall.chat) {
            $scope.currentCall.chat.offLocalAudio(false);
        }
    }
}
```

### I want that when event occur for turnOffLocalAudio it will wait until $scope.currentCall initialize. One way to solve this by creating a timer task to check the $scope.currentCall object until it resolved. Is there any good way by using angularjs promise API?

update my question with promise implementation

```
 app.controller('videoChat', function ($rootScope, $scope,$q) {

var deferred = $q.defer();

     $scope.invite = function () {
    // some variable ...
    var chat = new Chat(function uiCallback(action, options) {

            // other methods ...
         if (action === "peer.call.localstream") {
            _displayMessage("Starting local stream");
            _findElement('#myVideo').prop('src', URL.createObjectURL(options.payload));
            _findElement('#myVideo').css('display', 'inline');
            deferred.resolve();
        }

    });
    $scope.currentCall = {
        roomId: roomId,
        chat: chat,
        opponentId: String($scope.currentPatientId),
    };
    chat.connectSocket(remoteSocket, peerURL, id, roomId);
};

    $scope.changeLocalVideoStream = function () {
    var promise = deferred.promise;
    promise.then(function (result) {
        if ($scope.currentCall) {
            if ($scope.currentCall.chat) {
                    $scope.currentCall.chat.toggleLocalWebCam($scope.showLocalVideo);
            }
        }
    }, function (reason) {
        $log.error("unable to turn off local camera");
    });
}
```

Comment: How does $scope.currentCall get initialized?  Include that code in your question.

Comment: I updated my question with angularjs promise implementation. I just tested this and it working as expected. I never use promise before so one question regarding that is it not mandatory to use deferred.reject(); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is some function that returns a promise.  I just named it getCurrentCall.

```
function getCurrentCall() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  if (!$scope.currentCall) {
    $scope.currentCall = 'foo';
  }

  deferred.resolve();
  return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then you'd do this in your turnOffLocalRadio function:

```
$scope.turnOffLocalAudio = function() {
  getCurrentCall().then(function() {

    if ($scope.currentCall.chat) {
      $scope.currentCall.chat.offLocalAudio(false);
    }
  }, function() {
    // unable to get CurrentCall
  });
};
```